# state is not incrementing correctly reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add pagination to my react application. The problem is that my `this.state.id` is not incrementing correctly. When I'm pressing my second button with `id="2"`, the state is incrementing late and because of this, it is loading the old `this.state.id` data. I don't know what the problem is

My logic:

State is starting with 1, because that is the first page

`this.state = {id: 1}`

```
handleClick = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.id
    let nextValue = e.target.value
    if (nextValue === "Next") {
        this.setState({ id: this.state.id + 1 })
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ id: value })
    }
    console.log("This is value " + value)
    console.log(this.state.id)
    this.loadData(this.state.id)
    }
```

My pagination buttons:

```
<div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-12">
        <ul className="pagination justify-content-end">
            <li className="page-item"><button id="1" className="page-link" onClick={this.handleClick}>1</button></li>
            <li className="page-item"><button id="2" className="page-link" onClick={this.handleClick}>2</button></li>
            <li className="page-item"><button id="3" className="page-link" onClick={this.handleClick}>3</button></li>
            <li className="page-item"><button value="Next" className="page-link" onClick={this.handleClick}>Next</button></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

An example of what is happening:

When I press on the second button with id 2, it prints `This is value 2`, but `this.state.id` is still `1`. When I press on button 3, it prints `This is value 3`, but `this.state.id` is still `2`. This is causing my problem and it is fetching the wrong data for the page.

[image: My console.log]

Comment: print state inside render

Comment: `setState` isn't synchronous, so `this.state` won't be updated immediately after calling `setState`.

Comment: @SimpleJ Oh, do I need to use ```await``` then?

Comment: @GigaMeta `await` won't work, `setState` does not return a promise, you can use the callback `this.setState({ id: this.state.id + 1 }, () => console.log(this.state))`

Comment: i assume in `this.loadData` you get data from an api. then you probably have to set the state only after you get the data. not only the data state, but also the id. get the data of the new id, then setState of the new id and the received data

Comment: This issue is also explained in the React docs for setState: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState is asynchronous, refer https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-is-asynchronous-52ead919a3f0.

setState enables you to make a callback function after you set the state so you can get the real state. In your case

```
this.setState({id: value}, () => console.log(this.state.id));
```